# how to add a line number row, and sort by it

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, sorting, gridview

I have a Grid-view to which I recently added a new column for rowNo

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RowNo" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="lblRowNo" runat="Server"></asp:Literal>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The rowNo should allow sorting functionality, just as the other columns do.

I added a property to my Order object:

'RowNo
    Public rowNoVal As Integer
    Public Property rowNo As Integer
        Get
            Return rowNoVal
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            rowNoVal = value
        End Set
    End Property

I set the rowNo property in Data-Bound event and then assign it to the rowNo item template:

```
e.Row.DataItem.rowNo = e.Row.RowIndex + 1
DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblRowNo"), Literal).Text = 
e.Row.DataItem.rowNo
```

This shows by rowNo (asc):

```
RowNo   Created
1       5/29/2015 9:00:20 AM
2       5/29/2015 9:30:48 AM
3       5/29/2015 9:33:04 AM
4       5/29/2015 9:39:05 AM
5       5/29/2015 10:20:21 AM
6       5/29/2015 11:29:25 AM
7       5/29/2015 11:52:20 AM
```

And by rowNo (desc):

```
RowNo   Created
1       5/29/2015 11:52:20 AM
3       5/29/2015 10:20:21 AM
2       5/29/2015 11:29:25 AM
4       5/29/2015 9:39:05 AM
5       5/29/2015 9:33:04 AM
6       5/29/2015 9:30:48 AM
7       5/29/2015 9:00:20 AM
```

The orders are getting re-sorted by the sorting event, but the line numbers stay always in ascending order.

Thank you for your help.

**UPDATE W/ SOLUTION**

1. Added the loop that j.f. posted to the GetOrders() method.

   ```
   Dim i As Integer
   i = 1

   For Each order As Order In orderList.Items
       order.rowNo = i
       i += 1
   Next
   Me.gdvHeaders.Visible = True
   Me.gdvHeaders.DataSource = orderList.Items
   Me.gdvHeaders.DataBind()
   ```
2. Removed the incremental and assignment of rowNo from the grid-view's data-bound event:

   ```
   'Add rowNo
   e.Row.DataItem.rowNo = e.Row.RowIndex + 1
   DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblRowNo"), Literal).Text = 
   e.Row.DataItem.rowNo
   ```
3. Replaced #2 with:

   ```
   DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblRowNo"), Literal).Text = 
   e.Row.DataItem.rowNo
   ```

Now I can sort ASC|DESC using the rowNo column.

Many thanks to j.f. for the kind help and patience working towards a solution for my problem.

Comment: Before you bind your data to your GridView, could you add a new column to your data source for the row number? Or if you are querying a database,  add the row number to your query? Then use the row number like any other column.

Comment: I am not querying a database, the code invokes a service and I cannot modify the code in the service layer, unfortunately. In regards to your first recommendation, how can I add a new column to the data source for the row number?

Comment: My original thinking was that if you were using a DataTable, you could simply add another column. But, I see you are using a list of Order objects. I suppose adding a row number or ID property to your Order object may not make complete sense. That could work though. Another possibility would be to use a dictionary as your data source. The key could be used as a row number. That may require reworking your GridView, however.

Comment: Make sure you are adding the row number to the actual order object that is being bound to the GridView. What you are doing now is creating a brand new order, adding the row number, then setting the text. The actual order object's row number property is never set.

Comment: Thank you. How would I do this? I added the new order because I wasn't sure how to access the property.

Comment: Set the property at the same time you create the order objects initially, wherever that may be. Maybe in the `GetOrders()` method?

Comment: may be I should try to do it by using a dictionary?

Comment: That's up to you as the designer of the application. Based on the information given, I believe the two solutions I proposed should be able to work for you.

Comment: I am seeing the values now, but although the gridview gets sorted asc|desc by rowNo, the displayed numbers always show ascending. I will add an update to show what I did.

Comment: Definitely getting close! Your problem now is that since you are assigning the row number in your `DataBound` event, every time you bind your data, the row numbers will get set again - thus overwriting previous values. Assign the row number value _before_ you do your initial bind.

Comment: Will I have to do this in the OnInit event of the grid-view? I am sorry, this is challenging for me.

Comment: What do you mean? What you need to do is assign the row number value before the initial bind and never manipulate it again. It needs to behave just like any other property of `Order`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell how your logic flows with what I am seeing right now, but you need to assign the row number value *before your initial bind*. I am imagining something along these lines:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        BindGridViewInitial()
    End If

End Sub


Protected Sub BindGridViewInitial()

    List(Of Order) orders = Me.GetOrders()
    int i = 1;

    For Each order As Order In orders
        order.rowNo = i;
        i++;
    Next

    Me.gdvHeaders.DataSource = orders;
    Me.gdvHeaders.DataBind();

End Sub
```

Each `Order` will then have its own row number and you should be able to use it just like any other property.

When you assign the row number value in the `DataBound` handler of the GridView, then all you are doing is reassigning the values every time you bind the GridView, resulting in the values being overwritten.

Comment: It is working now. I updated the post with the solution. Many thanks, you were of great help.

Comment: You're welcome - glad you were able to figure it out!